# How to build only certain Jenkins jobs using "Stash Webhook to Jenkins" in a branch?

Tags: jenkins

I have enabled "Stash Webhook to Jenkins" for a branch called "develop". I have 10 jobs Jenkins configured on the branch develop for different purpose. 
When ever I merge a feature branch in to "develop" branch, all the 10 Jenkins jobs on `develop` are starting. I need only ONE Jenkins job to kick-off when ever there is a merge in to develop?
How do i configure this?

Thanks in advance
Hari

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Jenkins job from being triggered by Git commits by unckecking "Poll SCM" in job configuration. An [article](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/).